# What are the steps involved in updating Mysql db 5.7.30 to 5.7.35

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I need to patch update MySql db from 5.7.30 to 5.7.35
What are the steps involved?
Can I take mysqldump and just run yum update on below mysql packages
mysql-community-client.x86_64
mysql-community-common.x86_64
mysql-community-libs.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64
mysql-community-server.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely answer is simply:

1. take a dump (just for added safety)
2. use the installer to update
3. (make sure that `mysql_upgrade` was run -- I don't know if the yum stuff does such.)

That's an "upgrade in place"; no need to reload the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rick James. But isn't it mysql_upgrade instead of mysql_update?

Comment: @Jos - Thanks.  Fixed.